# How to use TimeToLiveConnectionTimeoutCallback in Oracle UCP

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, connection-pooling, ucp

How to use the TimeToLiveConnectionTimeoutCallback within Oracle UCP (Universal Connection Pool)?

I would expect that either the PoolDataSource or the UniversalConnectionPoolManager has an interface to register such a callback. And I would expect that such an interface would pass the concerned Connection by the interface. Neither is true.

It seems that I have to register an individual TimeToLiveConnectionTimeoutCallback to each UniversalPooledConnection which seems to me tricky, ugly (lots of UCP imports/glue code) and difficult (create a DataSource wrapper).

Or did I get something wrong?
Unfortunately the documentation remains silent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time passed, I realized that my assumption is true.
I have to register a callback to each `Connection` in a tricky and unelegant way.

I also opened a *support request* from oracle which confirmed this:

> void
>   registerTimeToLiveConnectionTimeoutCallback(TimeToLiveConnectionTimeoutCallback
>   cbk) throws java.sql.SQLException
>
> registers a time-to-live connection
>   timeout callback with a connection.
>
> The callback object is registered with
>   each pooled connection. It is an error
>   to register more than 1
>   TimeToLiveConnectionTimeoutCallbacks
>   on the same connection, or else you
>   will get an exception.
>
> As mentioned in it, the callback
>   object is registered with EACH pooled
>   connection.

Due to some other bugs and/or design flaws (of course, latter might be subjective) 
I decided to not UCP within my project.